# Datas values send by my android app = 0 on my database. Why?

Tags: php, android, database, http-post

This is an extract from my android code.
It works on my device, the latitude and longitude are updated.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
    final String latitude=Double.toString(location.getLatitude()); 
    final String longitude=Double.toString(location.getLongitude());                                                  this.textView.setText("latitude:"+latitude+"longitude"+longitude); 

new Thread(new Runnable() { 
@Override 
public void run() { 
HttpClient Client= new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost post= new HttpPost("/index2.php"); 
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
 pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));
 try { 
HttpResponse response = Client.execute(post); 
} 
catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
// TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } 
catch (IOException e) { 
// TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
 } 
}).start();
```

This is my phpcode :

```
<?php 
   mysql_connect("","","") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("");

   $query_add="insert into locations (latitude,longitude)values('".$_REQUEST['latitude']."','".$_REQUEST['longitude']."')";
   $query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 
   mysql_close();
 ?>
```

I receive the data on my database when the location changes but all values stock = 0.
Latitude and longitude are Double in my database.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing something with `pairs` after filling it with data? Also, beware of [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Oh thanks lol, i just missed this :
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));